# Serve a profile picture whose path is stored in database with Flask Python

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am trying to serve a profile picture whose path is stored in the sqlalchemy database.

The snippet code is :

```
@employees.route('/upload-picture/<full_name>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def upload(full_name):
    if not current_user.is_employee:
        abort(403)
    borrower = Borrower.query.filter_by(full_name=full_name).first()
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'photo' in request.files:
    profile_pic = photos.save(request.files['photo'])
        borrower.profile_pic = profile_pic
        db.session.add(borrower)
        db.session.commit()
    return render_template('employees/borrower.html', borrower=borrower)

@employees.route('/uploaded_profile_pic/<filename>')
@login_required
def uploaded_profile_pic(filename):
    if not current_user.is_employee:
        abort(403)
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
```

My template file is as follows:

```
  {% if borrower.profile_pic %}
        <img src="{{ url_for('employees.uploaded_profile_pic', filename = borrower.profile_pic)}}" />
    {% else %}
    <form action="{{url_for('employees.upload', full_name=borrower.full_name)}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="photo"><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>
    {% endif %}
```

The problem is i keep getting a broken image on the template.

Comment: Sorry for the silly question: are you sure the path is to an image? I ask because I got a broken image when my file was not an image.

Comment: Its not silly. I also suspect that is the problem but I cant seem to notice the problem within the code.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but wouldn't that be a problem with the path and not with the code?

Comment: I have just noticed that my uploads path was wrong so i fixed it to app.config['UPLOADED_PHOTOS_DEST'] = 'app/static/uploads'

Comment: Aha! Good job finding that.

Comment: And changed my url to      <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename = borrower.profile_pic)}}" />. On inspection it confirms it has gone into the static folder but it doesnt go into the uploads folder

Comment: Ah, ok. See roy's answer.

Comment: If i remove the uploads folder within the static folder, the code works just fine but if i have another folder within static for purposes of organisation, nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The [save](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage.save) function is used to save the file permanently to your filesystem,it does not create the path. You need to create the path to a specific image and save it as an attribute  `self.profile_pic = profile_pic` which will return the image path when accessed as `{{ borrower.profile_pic }}`.

```
<img src="{{ borrower.profile_pic }}">  

if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
```

Comment: How do i organise my uploaded files within different folders

Comment: As i explained to bernie right above, I wish to organise my profile pictures in one folder and other necessary documents in other folders as necessary.

Comment: @KimaniNdegwa then you can have different directories under static i.e. `/static/img` , `/static/docs` and include them in your config. You'll have to select destination from your views when uploading the file say a button for images and one for pdf or docs.